# How can I update specific field after retrieved in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can I update specific field after retrieved in django rest framework

```
# Models.py
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    view = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I want to update view after read a specific data.

```py
# Views.py
class ArticleDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    # Update view + 1 

# serializers.py
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = "__all__"
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

If you want your field to be incremented only on a `GET` request, you can update it in the `retrieve` method:

```py
# views.py
class ArticleDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        instance.view = instance.view + 1
        instance.save()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

If you want it to be incremented with both `GET` and `PATCH`, you could update it in `get_object` instead:

```py
# views.py
class ArticleDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        instance = super(ArticleDetail, self).get_object()
        instance.view = instance.view + 1
        instance.save()
        return instance
```